# Restored my site using a backup. Seems to be OK but the posts are empty?

Tags: backup

Hope you all can help me. I made a stupid mistake and tried to clean up some of my unused categories and found out later on that it broke my site. How can deleting a category break your site?

Unfortunately, I wasn't able to do a backup and asked my webhost [FatCow](http://www.fatcow.com/) to do a site restore.

They gave me a backup which I used to restore the site.

The site currently looks ok from the outside, but if you click the posts, most of it is either empty or incomplete! Only the first part is showing.

Some posts are complete but most aren't.

Is there anything else I can do? Hope you guys can help me.

My website is http://www.swimbikerun.ph

Comment: If you go to the Dashboard and edit a post, is the content there?

Answer (score 1):

You might be able to get a better backup from them of the database. It sounds like that has been compromised. If you get that, even from a while ago, it may be better than what you're up against.

If that doesn't work Google Caches sites regularly. To get google's cache go to the search bar and type cache:yourdomain.com and you should be able to browser the last cached version of your site.

Answer (score 0):

Unfortunately it sounds like the backups are incomplete, or old.

Looking through a webscraper such as Google (cache) and archive.org (WayBackMachine) you should be able to recover the rest of your data.

Best of luck